# How to speed up data fitting and get percentile function

Tags: python, performance, numba, data-fitting, processing-efficiency

I have a 1 dimensional array. I want to get a certain percentile(say,5%) of the fitting of this data(Monte Carlo method is best, guassian KDE method is also OK) as fast as possible. Because this function is used millions of times.

My way is using the scipy gaussian_kde.

My question is:

1. Any other ways to get higher speed of gaussian_kde?
   Main cost is `kde = gaussian_kde(x, bw_method=0.02) #about 220us`

Answer (score 0):

You seems to rewrite a well-optimized function of Numpy called **`np.quantile`**. Calling `np.quantile(x, 0.05)` provide the exact/accurate 5% quantile and is 4 times faster than your optimized implementation! Note that if you need to call this functions a lot of time on different *independent* arrays, then you can speed up the computation even more thanks to *Numba parallelism*.

Comment: I think OP is looking for np.percentile(x, 5). 5 here represents the 5th percentile along a given axis.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html.

Comment: @VRComp yes, it works too.  Both provide the same results and are equally fast in this case. Thanks for this information.

Comment: @JérômeRichard  Thanks for the comment, but here the data fitting is necessary. you will find the results of  np.percentile(x, 5) and halfSearch(x,0.05) are not exactly the same. About Numba parallelism, I have already set this function to be called independently millions of times in every core, so parallelize this function won't help here.